# How to write a formula to check engaged IDs in excel

Tags: excel, formula

I have an excel table where I need to check ID is engaged or not. For similar requirements, the same ID is extended with '_' then incremental numbers.

If Column 'Item' is not zero then Column 'Engaged' should be Yes and the same for all IDs having '*', if any of it has non zero value in Column 'Item' then all IDs having '*' become yes. Attaching excel table image.

I need to write a formula to automate the column 'Engaged' so manual mistakes can be avoided—many thanks.

[Excel view of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaPsQ.png)

Comment: Try with countifs(), criteria as ID and not zero or greater or equal to 1.

Comment: Thank you Solar for the idea, it worked.